# Spring inbound adapter, multiple listener vs one

Tags: spring-integration

i am new to spring sftp integration. i have a use case that there are multiple tenants folders under same root folder(let's assume that sub folder here can go in multiple level deep, for example: root_folder/tenant1/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4).  I am wondering if we should create on inbound adapter to listen the file change on the root folder, or should be more specific on the tenant folder. would anyone tell me the pro and con on those?

one listener on root folder:
pro:
can't think of anything. simply, less code?
con:
1. this may ended create more listeners(or is this support) to listener all the sub folders.

multiple listeners per each tenants:
pro:
1. easy to control since it is 1-1 mapping.
2. number of listeners are controlled.
con:
1. performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inbound channel adapter doesn't look at subfolders so you really don't have an option except having an adapter for each subfolder.

You might want to consider using the outbound gateway instead - it supports recursive directory listing and mget.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. is anything pro and con by using outbound gateway vs multiple inbound adapter?

Comment: It depends on your requirements - the inbound adapter synchronizes the remote directory with the local one, has filters to prevent duplicates etc. The gateway is a lower-level programming model.